# A good hook to check authorization and redirect?

Tags: hooks, redirect, actions, wp-redirect, privileges

It seems strange to put a redirect in a template page, because so much of the page has already been built by the time you reach a custom page template.

I'm wondering what is a good action hook to use where I can test whether the user's logged in, and whether they're on a particular page/category/etc and `wp_redirect` them if necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the built-in `template_redirect` action is the best for this... :D

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect